# mysql str_to_date returns null

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is my query for getting date from string but it returns `null` even if the date format is right, time-duration field contains data like `07:00AM`

```
SELECT time_duration FROM time_table  
GROUP by STR_TO_DATE(time_duration, '%%l:%%i%%p')
```

Comment: Try `%H%i%p` ..

Comment: You have too many % signs. One per letter.

Comment: @sagi , im using 12 hour format,and i have also tried with %.

Comment: Are you sure you're field contains `07:00AM`? I tried `select STR_TO_DATE('07:00AM', '%l:%i%p');` locally and got `07:00:00`

Comment: i m getting same as you but when i replace string with data field 'time_duration' having data same as static value   it returns null

Comment: Try `SELECT time_duration,STR_TO_DATE(time_duration, '%l:%i%p') FROM time_table` to compare the actual field to what str_to_date is creating. You can also probably just group by the field without converting it.

Comment: @aynber this is my code 

$sql_get_timetable= sprintf("SELECT tt.time_table_id,sa.standard,STR_TO_DATE(tt.time_duration, '%%l:%%i%%p'),tt.room_lab_no,tt.time_duration,ss.name,wd.week_day_name  from time_table tt 
    left JOIN superAdmin_subjects ss on tt.subject=ss.id
    left  JOIN week_day wd  on tt.week_day=wd.week_day_id
   left  JOIN superAdmin_standards sa  on tt.standard_id=sa.id
    WHERE tt.standard_id=%d  AND  tt.school_id=%d GROUP by STR_TO_DATE(tt.time_duration, '%%l:%%i%%p') order BY STR_TO_DATE(tt.time_duration, '%%l:%%i%%p')",$standard_id,$school_id);

Comment: My point was to check the actual values of the field and to check if any of the conversions were working.

Comment: yes i did the same but it returns null at that point

Comment: what is the type of the time_duration column? I'm a bit suspicious that a duration would have am/pm.  If an activity took 13 hours I wouldn't record that as 01:00PM.

Comment: duration is just name it's just  store the time, it's type is varchar(15)

Comment: its works fine in my local environment having mysql client version 5.0.11 but makes problem in live having 5.5.31-38.2 version,this is my query
it returns '7:00:00' in local and  'null' in live
SELECT tt.time_duration, STR_TO_DATE(tt.time_duration, '%l:%i %p')  from time_table tt